# Get Facebook Embedded iframe video and post height

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, iframe

I am trying to get the iframe height of the embedded facebook video and posts on my webpage. Since I am embedding a lot of different posts and videos, I am only **specifying the width of the iframe, but not the height**. Like the code here:

For video:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbbcnews%2Fvideos%2F10153836161582217%2F&show_text=1&width=560" width="560" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

For Posts:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F9gag%2Fposts%2F10154878302591840&width=500" width="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Right now if I only specify the width, I got a iframe that is cut in half.[Video example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUPMm.png)

My question is, it there a way to get **the height of the content after the content has been rendered** for the embedded video and posts. Is there a javascript way? or perhaps an API call that I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: Don’t those automatically adapt in height, if you embed them via the JS SDK? (As you are supposed to, instead of putting iframe elements into your page directly.)

Comment: @CBroe I wanted to use iframe directly so the loading time would be faster

Comment: Well, you can’t have it all. The iframe content is loaded from a different domain, so you have no access to it to measure its height. Therefor you need the “help” of Facebook if you want to have them adapt to the content height; and that help comes in the form of the JS SDK.

Answer (score -2):

If content of your iframe is on a different domain, you can't get access to its internals. That would be cross-site scripting.

So the best solution would be to pass the `height` in your query string in `src` property of you `iframe` and get the height of your `iframe` from its parent frame.

Example below:

```js
var elm = document.getElementById('iframeFb');
console.log('iframe height is: ', elm.height);
```

```html
<iframe id="iframeFb" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbbcnews%2Fvideos%2F10153836161582217%2F&show_text=1&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: But different posts would have different height depending on the amount of text or context it has, which would be impossible to set the same height for all the embedded content. I'm trying to find a way so that I can adjust the height dynamically.

Comment: @KChi considering creating iframes code with adjusted hight for each post accordingly to your content, otherwise use JS SDK. If you find my answer useful, please show your appreciation considering up voting it :) thanks!